# How can I set up a database through an npm package in a Docker container?

Tags: postgresql, docker, npm, docker-compose, prisma

I have a project that uses prisma and postgres for database management, I have this project setup as an npm package in an effort to centralize it, as it will be used across multiple *other* different projects, so it is installed via `npm i <project-db>`.

I am currently trying to set up a docker-compose file so that I can create the tables needed when setting up a fresh install of one of my projects that requires the database, but I'm not sure how to go about doing this since the database/prisma are all being managed by an npm package, and not directly. How would I go about setting things up so that when I run docker-compose, all the tables are created?

In case that is a bit confusing of an explanation, I'll attempt to lay it out in a diagram to explain it better:

```
Project A (Node project, setup as a docker service)
     - contains `project-db` as a dependency in package.json

project db (separate repository published to the npm registry)
     - contains prisma schema
     - has install scripts to setup prisma and deploy the db 

postgres (setup as a docker service)
     - what prisma uses as the database
```

So I need to somehow run the scripts in "project db" when going through the docker compose setup, but I don't know how. I've attached both my Dockerfile for Project A as well as the docker compose script. Because Project A needs the database tables in order to do anything, it errors out when I build the project.

Dockerfile (Project A)

```
ARG OWNER
FROM node:20-buster-slim
ENV NODE_ENV 'development'
ENV OWNER "username"

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install libssl-dev ca-certificates -y

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json
COPY package*.json .

# Setup npmrc
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=TOKEN \
    TOKEN=$(cat /run/secrets/TOKEN) && \
    echo //npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=${TOKEN} >> ~/.npmrc
RUN echo @${OWNER}:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/ >> ~/.npmrc

# Copy src files
COPY src/ src/

# Install packages
RUN npm ci
# ^ installs "project db" as a dependency

# remove github token from npmrc
RUN echo > ~/.npmrc

# Build the project
RUN npm run build

# Run the start script in package.json
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

```
services:
  postgres:
        image: postgres:16.2
        container_name: postgres
        hostname: postgres
        environment:
            POSTGRES_USER: ${PSQL_USER}
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${PSQL_PASS}
            POSTGRES_DB: ${PSQL_DB_NAME}
        ports:
            - ${PSQL_PORT}:${PSQL_PORT}
        restart: 'unless-stopped'
        volumes:
            - 'pg-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
        healthcheck:
            test: ['CMD-SHELL', 'pg_isready -q -d $$POSTGRES_DB -U $$POSTGRES_USER']
            interval: 10s
            timeout: 5s
            retries: 5
  projectA:
        build: 
            context: .
            secrets:
                - TOKEN
        container_name: projectA
        depends_on:
            postgres:
                condition: service_healthy
        tty: true
        env_file:
            - src/.env
volumes:
  pg-data:
    driver: local
secrets:
    TOKEN:
        environment: "TOKEN"
```

Comment: A Dockerfile can never reach another container.  It sounds like there's a bug in your build system where the project build depends on a running database; can you fix this?  (What happens if the database is deleted and recreated after the image is built, or if you `docker push` the image to a registry and the target system has an empty database?)

Comment: Yeah that's what I've realized as I've been debugging this - I guess my best option would be to just write a script to create the tables myself, but I thought prisma handled something like that already via their prisma migrate function, but it looks like that probably won't work in this scenario.